# Why doesn't the delay time option work for my tooltip?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui-tooltip

Ive created a simple tooltip using bootstrap and JQuery. But the delay time for the tooltip simply doesn't work for me. Its taking obviously longer than 100 milliseconds.

HTML:

```
<p class="myHover" onclick="jobFunction()" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!" data-delay=100>GIS Researcher</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".myHover").tooltip(); 
});
```

Ive properly referenced bootstrap and jQuery in my head tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works fine for me. Your fiddle didn't load any of the required libraries.

I changed your paragraph to a `span` and set the tooltip placement to bottom to make it show up in a more sensible location.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".myHover").tooltip();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<span class="myHover" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!" data-delay="100" data-placement="bottom">GIS Researcher</span>
```

Comment: Nice! Beat me to the answer.

Comment: I loaded all libraries and changed the paragraph to span but it still does not work at all. Here is the complete html & CSS: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3tjojwc4jj5cy42/CV2.zip?dl=0

Comment: I've demonstrated in the above snippet that it works. Have you tried to run it?

Comment: Your `script` tag for loading jQuery is not correctly closed. You're missing the closing `>`. This results in your bootstrap Javascript not being loaded.

Comment: Aha. Thanks alot! could you tell me why would you use <span> instead of a <p> element?

Comment: Because it's an inline element while `p` is a block-level element. Because block-level elements take a width of 100% of the surrounding container by default, and your tooltip appears in the middle of the element, it will show up at an odd location. Of course, all of this can be modified using CSS.